# Angular 11 - HostListener event listen for ctrl + mouse left click?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to listen for ctrl + left mouse click event.

I'm able to capture the ctrl click but how do i combine it with the left mouse click.

```
 @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event.key)
    if (event.key == 'Control'){
      console.log(true)
     }
    }
```

this is what I have for the ctrl click.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about having two key event listeners and a global variable? For example (vanilla JS): `let ctrlPress = false; document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) { if(e.key == 'Control') { ctrlPress = true} }); document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e) { if(e.key == 'Control') { ctrlPress = false} });` . Then, you would do something like `yourelement.addEventListener('click',function() {  if(ctrlPress) { /* do your stuff */ }  });` . Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/2CA4s55j).

Comment: document:mousedown, and [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) has ctrlKey and button properties

Answer (score 0):

`event.key == 'Control'` checks is control pressed as separate event. You need event.ctrlKey whick is boolean and represents whether control been pressed during the event (in your case click) or not. So just listen click event, and when it is triggered check `if(event.ctrlKey)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the **CTRL Key** is pressed or not from **event.ctrlKey**

```js
@Directive({ selector: '[wtCtrlClickDirective]', standalone: true })
export class CtrlClickDirective {

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  ctrlClickEventHandler(event: MouseEvent) {

    if (event.ctrlKey) {

      console.log('CTRL + Left Click');

    } else {

      console.log('Just click');

    }

  }
}
```